# Hide input-help on form using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm currently learning AngularJS and i would like to accomplish a simple task.
On a form input, i would like to hide corresponding 'input-help' even data entered in input is invalid.
The way i'm currently doing this invoke some jquery. But i'm searching the way to do it using AngularJS logic. I think i should use directive but as i'm new to angular, i don't know exactly how to do it.

Here is the jsFiddle sample code working using jquery: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wr5bk/)

And here is the jsFiddle sample code not working (no jquery): [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TnPpm/)
{For test, enter just few text in password input and blur it}

This is the code i have: {jquery}

```
$(document).on('blur', '.immediate-help', function () {
    $(this).next('.input-help').fadeOut();
}).on('focus', '.immediate-help', function () {
    $(this).next('.input-help').fadeIn();
});
```

This works as expected but i would like to use angular directive to do it. Of course, i'm not against using jquery in angular directive.

So, to resume, i would like when blur input is triggered to hide 'input-help' even the text is not valid and using angular directive.

Could someone show me the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several approaches:

**Using script in directive:**

`elm` argument within directive `link` callback is a jQuery object if jQuery.js loads before anugular.js in page... or it is a jQlite if jQuery.js not included.

jQlite has many of the most common jQuery methods so you can use :

```
elm.bind('blur....
```

See **[angular.element docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element)** for list of jQlite methods.

**Using `ng-class`**

Give form and controls a `name`. This creates an object `formName` with properties represented by field names. You can then use angular expressions for classes, or properties like `disabled` within markup

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input name="passord"/>
    <div ng-class="{ShowMeClassName: myForm.password.$invalid}"> Error content</div>
</form>
```

`ng-class` will toggle the class `ShowMeClassName` depending on validity of field named `password` within form named `myForm`

Comment: Thx for input but i don't understand where should i bind elm blur event in directive?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wr5bk/2/ ... using same directive for validation...note I changed order of angular/jQUery loading so could use `fade` animations which aren't supported in `jQlite`

Comment: Ok works now (without using delegation in your jsfiddle)  Thank you!

Comment: one important trick, not relevant to this situation but you will encounter it... if elements are being created on the fly and directive needs to do manipulation...wrap code in `$timeout` . Even with zero delay it gives angular compiling diges a chance to finish

Comment: only talking about manipulation or code that can't use dlegation. Agin, is not aplicable to this situation unless your form controls are built on the fly

Comment: Thank to point me that, btw you save me some headhaches concerning the fact to load jquery before angular compile. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/).

Angular-UI provides a bunch of directives, which can help you. You have the ui-event directive.

For example you can use

```
<input ui-event="{ blur : 'blurCallback()' }">
...
<script>
$scope.blurCallback = function() {
alert('Goodbye');
};
</script>
```

Comment: If i get it, Angular-ui is a 'addon' or is it implemented by default in angular js source?

Comment: AngularUI it is an 'addon' which you have to include in your scripts.